# is there any way to make Dart/Flutter run JS code via a port or a channel on Dart VM platforms

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

first, I am not talking about regular JS code functions or libraries for the web, since I know this is possible and can be done via the `js` library.

I want to know if I can achieve this on Android/iOS as example, so I can import libraries to run somehow in the device, then bind it to a Dart interface.

Any ideas about this?